# Missing letter č in ReportLab pdf created with Python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf-generation, reportlab

A couple of days ago I started to use ReportLab with Python34. It's pretty nice package but I have one big problem that I don't know how to overcome.

Could someone check my code and help me get over this? The problem is connected with letter č in Slovenian language. In the title there is no problem, but later in pdf file I cannot see that letter.

My code is below:

```
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Paragraph, Spacer
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet
from reportlab.rl_config import defaultPageSize
from reportlab.lib.units import inch

from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('Vera', 'Vera.ttf'))

PAGE_HEIGHT=defaultPageSize[1]
PAGE_WIDTH=defaultPageSize[0]
styles = getSampleStyleSheet()

Title = "Izračun pokojnine"
bogustext =("""ččččččččččččččččččč""")

def myPage(canvas, doc):
    canvas.saveState()
    canvas.setFont('Vera',16)
    canvas.drawCentredString(PAGE_WIDTH/2.0, PAGE_HEIGHT-108, Title)
    canvas.restoreState()

def go():
    doc = SimpleDocTemplate("phello.pdf")
    Story = [Spacer(1,2*inch)]
    style = styles["Normal"]
    p = Paragraph(bogustext, style)
    Story.append(p)
    Story.append(Spacer(1,0.2*inch))
    doc.build(Story, onFirstPage=myPage)

go()
```

When I make pdf file I get this:
[image]

Why there is a difference between letter č in title and text?

Thanks in advance!

Best regards, David

Comment: python 2.x or 3.x?

Comment: @joel goldstick: Python 3.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in the title you are using `Vera` as the font, in the text you are using the default font used by Reportlab which is `Times-Roman` (if I remember correctly).

The blackboxes you're seeing indicate that the current font (`Times-Roman`) doesn't have a symbol for the character you are trying to display. So to fix it you will have to change the font of the text to a font that does contain a symbol for č. One way to do this is by creating a new style Like this:

```
ParagraphStyle('MyNormal',
               parent=styles['Normal'],
               fontName='Vera')
```

In some cases it might be easier to replace the missing symbols with the symbol form a fallback font in which case you might want to check out [this answer I posted earlier this year.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35172207/reportlab-working-with-chinese-unicode-characters/35371704#35371704)

Comment: Many many thanks to @B8vrede :) It works like a charm. Before reading your answer I almost got to the same solution by myself.... but I must admit that you helped me a lot :) Thanks again!